# Gridview : Unwanted Cell appearing at top of Gridview when using "Columns"

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I had two cells appearing before "Columns" on my code where I show two rows with data in. I added  Showheader ="False" which removed one but now I still have a single cell before my main display of data (for one item thing Employee details). In the code I have put in "123" & "456" (as you will see below) the "123" appears before the cell and the "456" appears in the first row in the first cell (as you would expect) so how and what is the first row single cell and where does it come from?!

I hope the below code snippet is enough as I believe it to be something to do with Gridview?!

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                CellPadding="0" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   Showheader ="False" 
                                ShowFooter="False" AllowSorting="false" 
                                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" EnableViewState="true"
                                EnableModelValidation="True" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display - Please change your search.">

                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr>123
                                                <td>456
                                                    <span>UPRN</span>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBtest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SHOPCODE")%>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SHOPCODE")%>'
                                                        CommandName="CmdPropertyClickToSearch" CssClass="ButtonTextual" OnCommand="btnPropertyToSearch_Click" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span>Postcode</span>
```

Comment: The gridview will render an HTML table and each Item template will be a cell (i.e. `<td></td>`). You can't have a `<tr></tr>` inside a cell so it looks like you are just rendering invalid HTML and what your are likely seeing is the browser trying to make the best of a bad job. Alter your `ItemTemplate` to render valid HTML.

Comment: Hi Ben, okay that sounds great. Sorry for just asking but how do I make the 'ItemTemplate' render HTML? Essentially how do I hide that or do I put a TD around the outside? (off to play but ask as well) :-)

Comment: It will render whatever you have within `<ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>` within a `<td></td>` so in the example you have posted the first thin I would do to make it valid is wrap the whole thing in a `<table>/table>`.

Comment: Thanks, added a table after itemtemplate  <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table > and that's put a border around, so now just to tidy the CSS to hide it. Thanks! If you put it as the answer I'll mark it :-)

Comment: If you want to specify your own `<table>` declaration it is cleaner and simpler to use a `Repeater` rather than a `Gridview` - as pointed out `Gridview` will render html table itself which can be restrictive. Post up the code you ended up with so we can see.

Comment: Chris is Repeater the best when I am only displaying one set of results?